# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 error on Zapier

Tags: api, zapier

I am trying to use Zapier to connect to my API, but I keep getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Not sure what to do, I don't have much experience with javascript. So any help will be appreciated! Here is the code I use:

```
var url = "MY API REQUEST URL";
var headers = {
             "Accept": "application/json",
             "headers":{"Authorization": "MY API TOKEN"}
             };

  // Call the API
  var response = fetch(url, headers);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  callback(data);
```

Comment: Can you show the output (or a small section thereof) of the data in the JSON (`response` variable)

Comment: This is what my data looks like in JSON: 
[18-05-01 03:39:09:213 PDT] [[{positions_mobile={2018-04-18=101, 2018-04-19=101, 2018-04-12=101, 2018-04-23=101

This is under the snytax error I get from Zapier:
Object.parse (native)
  theFunction (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:19:19)
  eval (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:24:5)
  Domain.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:53:5)
  Domain.run (domain.js:221:14)
  module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)

Comment: I'll leave any actually answer to someone who knows JavaScript better, but that doesn't appear to be valid JSON which is why it would be failing.

Comment: You could try an online JSON lint service to check it thoroughly

Comment: Just checked it and there are some errors:

"  Error: Parse error on line 2:
 [  [{    positions_mobile = {
----------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'  "

But how do I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your comments what's actual json vs error messages, but I would take a gander at https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/json/, which describes the (quite simple) structure of a json document. Namely, there are no `=`, which might be your problem.

Comment: Separately, it looks like your js code won't work as expected. I'd more closely follow the example here: https://zapier.com/help/code/#weather-json-api-call

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to make a web request, why don't you try using the [Webhooks app](https://zapier.com/help/webhooks/)?

If you still need to use the code step, see the example [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-http-example).

The error here is because you are trying to parse something that is not JSON as JSON. I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49962300/3514632).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use webhook - Retrieve poll but i get an "  'dict' object has no attribute 'swapcase' " error. Do you know what I could be missing, I filled in the field for url and headers.